# Tenant resolution using http referer header in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi-tenancy project built with .NET Core. Previously there has been multiple deployment of the API for each tenant and I want to change this with a single deployment of API for all tenants. In this case, I am not able to use `HttpContext.Request.Host`.

I want to use the `HTTP Referer` header to get the domain where the request has been initiated.

My question is that, I am not sure if we will always have the full domain name in this header. I checked the project, the project is sending this header with each request, but still is there any scenario where we end up not having any data in this header?

Comment: Bookmark or typed (null origin and no referrer).... and if you are looking for .host, that's not necessarily referrer. So a link from Google results the referrer would be google.  Some sites/browsers also block referrer.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/noreferrer  What's the use-case?  Sounds like maybe you just want to use/distribute API keys.

Comment: I want to get my tenant from their domain name. like tenanta.somesite.com, tenantb.anothersite.com . The domains are all different for tenants. The API is hosted on a different domain like api.myapp.com. So using the HttpContext.Request.Host is not suitable in this case.  The other workaround is to use a custom header in the requests but I don't want to change anything in the frontend at the moment.

Comment: I suppose referrer would be good enough as long as the first GET is the same page for all.  You get that from Request.Headers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.headers.requestheaders.referer?view=aspnetcore-8.0  On the first Ajax call it should be set, so you'd branch from there.   Consider security implications, though, as I believe this header can be modified.  (Origin cannot but it doesn't seem to be in ASP.NET requestheaders... maybe can get from CORS middleware?)

Comment: So you can get referrer and origin via: var origin = HttpContext.Request.Headers.Origin;
var referrer = HttpContext.Request.Headers.Referer;   However, for some reason the Origin always comes through as null.  Not sure why that is... since it is in the request if I copy/paste the HAR file from Chrome's dev tools.  (though not shown in the dev tools console strangely enough...)

Comment: If you don't want to modify the frontends, seems like you'd need to assign per user.  Store it in the user's identity.  (maybe make a role for it?)